# Adding Youtube player within RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, youtube-api, android-cardview

I am building an application in which I want to use **Youtube** API for running videos but the problem is that the **youtube** API is copied to all card items where I dont want it to come, I only want a specific post where the video can be played and not on all posts. I am also using **RecyclerView** and **cardView** in this application with **Firebase** as my database.please help me reduce this redundancy problem, I have researched many questions but did not found anything useful. Is there any way by which the video can only be played on some post of cardView and not on all. for example **facebook** application or **instagram** application where videos come on specific posts and not on all.

> I am using Android Studio

**Youtube FirebaseAdapter class file:**

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

        post.class,
        R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
        postViewHolder.class,
        mDatabaseReference
) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setYoutube(model.getYoutube());
    }
};
mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}

public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder{

View mView;

public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}
public void setYoutube(final String youtube){
    final YouTubePlayerView youPlay = (YouTubePlayerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.youtuber);
    youPlay.initialize("SOME KEY",
            new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtube);
                }
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            });
}
```

**youtube CardView xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtuber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Comment: you can separately inflate a fragment having only youtube player

Comment: @phpdroid can you please explain me how to do so, coz i dont know how to use fragments properly

Comment: i wish i had some similar snippet but you can go through some fragment tutorials on youtube

Comment: Did you try and use [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)? Here is a sample code for [how to use a YouTubePlayerFragment to play a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment).